# simple_html_dom: 403 Access denied

Tags: php

I implemented this function in order to parse HTML pages using two different "methods".
As you can see both are using the very handy class called `simple_html_dom`.
The difference is the first method is also using curl to load the HTML while the second is not using curl

Both methods are working fine on a lot of pages but I'm struggling with this specific call:
`searchThroughDOM('https://fr.shopping.rakuten.com/offer/buy/3458931181/new-york-1997-4k-ultra-hd-blu-ray-blu-ray-bonus-edition-boitier-steelbook.html', 'simple_html_dom');`

In both cases, I end up with a 403 access denied response.
Did I do something wrong?
Or is there another method in order to avoid this type of denial?

```
function searchThroughDOM ($url, $method)
{
    echo '$url = '.$url.'<br>'.'$method = '.$method.'<br><br>';
    $time_start = microtime(true);

    switch ($method) {
        case 'curl':
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36');
            $str = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);

            // Create a DOM object
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            // Load HTML from a string
            $html->load($str);
            break;

        case 'simple_html_dom':
            $html = new simple_html_dom();
            $html->load_file($url);
            break;
    }

    $collection = $html->find('h1');

    foreach($collection as $x => $x_value) {
        echo 'x = '.$x.' => value = '.$x_value.'<br>';
    }

    $html->save('result.htm');
    $html->clear();

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    echo 'Elapsed Time (DOM) = '.($time_end - $time_start).'<br><br>';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From my point of view , there is nothing wrong with "simple_html_dom" 
you may remove the simple html dom "part" of the code , leave only for the CURL 
which I assume is the source of the problem.
There are lots of reasons cause the curl Not working on page 
first of all I can see you add

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
you should also try to add  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false

Secondly , check your curl version, see if it is too old 
third option, if none of above working , you may want to enable cookie , it may possible the cookie disabled cause the website detect it is machine, not real person send the request .
lastly , if all above attempt failed , try other library or even file_get_content ,
Curl is not your only option, of cause it is the most powerful one.

Comment: Hi Dharman , of course you "MUST SWITCH OFF" in this case for two reasons , 1 to get out if it is CURL cause the problem or Not ,if you turn off the checking and the 403 is Gone, you know where the problem is.   2 the server of "fr.shopping.rakuten.com" is not under control of "StfA" you can't ask him/her to write email to "fr.shopping.rakuten.com" say "Hi Guys install some serious SSL certificate "for me to so I can grab your webpage for me/my boss. if the webiste using self signed Cpanel certificated switch off "VERIFYHOST" is a MUST if you want to get the JOB DONE, am I correct ?

Comment: Hi Dharman, it would be nice if you can simply accept that I am correct in this case and give the people who was/is/willbe puzzled by this problem a correct way to sort out, many thanks

Comment: I cannot accept anything. If OP didn't accept your answer then it means it probably didn't help them. From my side I have already said that switching the validation off is almost never a good idea. I will not start arguing with you over it.